# Plot something on lat long in PHP

Tags: mapping, php, plot

Is there some sort of plotting system which lets you do this? (in PHP):
ex. `plot(lat,long,data_show_onhover)`

My CSV file that I want to plot on the map looks like this:
something,something,something,something,something,Lat,Long,something,something,something,something,something,something,something
So when I hover on the area of lat,long it shows rest of data in array.

I'm using repl.it so there's no root and I want to avoid using google maps because it's paid.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: is your data in a file or database? please give a little more information.

Comment: i edited the question.